# Cascade Shadow Maps Shrinking

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've adapted the Nvidia CSM example to work on the Opengl core profile using GLM for the math.  However, I have noticed a problem which I think is related to scaled models.  The shadows seem to shrink the closer I am to them.

In the fragment shader I get the shadow coordinate like so:

```
vec4 shadow_coord = textureMatrix[index] * vec4(positionCS, 1.0);
```

In the vertex shader I make positionCS like so (modelView is V * M):

```
positionCS = (modelView * vertPosition).xyz;
```

I read somewhere that I should be using the inverse transpose of the model matrix if the model matrix scales the mesh, but that particular example was multiplying the normal vector and not the position vector.  I tried it anyway but it simply breaks the shadow mapping completely.

Any ideas?

It seems to only do it on the closer splits of the CSM.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it.  The Nvidia example was missing the Z scale/offsets for the crop matrix (poor demo?).

I added them in where I create the crop matrix and the problem went away:

```
float scaleZ = 1.0f / (maxZ - minZ);
float offsetZ = -minZ * scaleZ;
shadCrop[2][2] = scaleZ;
shadCrop[2][3] = offsetZ;
```

I've now got some slight artifacts on the furthest split, but I haven't set any bias just yet.